# How to join multiple rows sequentially in a numpy array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I've a data like this,

```
data = [array(['a', 'b', 'c']), 
        array([['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]), 
        array([['j', 'k', 'l'], ['m', 'n', 'o'], ['p', 'q', 'r']])]
```

I want to join values in inner list sequentially. This is the desired output that I need.

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d g', 'e h', 'f i'], ['j m p', 'k n q', 'l o r']]
```

I tried using using multiple loops and join but it's not giving me required output.

```
for i in data:
    for j in i:
        print(" ".join(j))
```

I'm not really sure on how to achieve this? Need an efficient and faster approach because my original data is really large.

Comment: That's not a NumPy array, though? You're not going to get any performance improvement if all you do is loop over a NumPy array, by the way.

Comment: @AMC actually it's a numpy array but I posted it as normal list.

Comment: Why...? What are you using the arrays for?

Comment: @AMC I was given this data. I didn't prepare it this way. What would you suggest? I have large data in which I want this desired output. It's a list of numpy arrays.

Comment: Is it a list of NumPy ndarrays, or is it a multidimensional ndarray? I'm trying to convert the data you shared properly.

Comment: @AMC I've updated the question on how the data actually is. Also values are not just strings there are timestamps as well along with strings.

Comment: The output should be a list of list, or list of arrays?

Comment: @AMC Both is fine. Which every can provide faster approach.

Comment: I'm trying to come up with something at least somewhat clean, it's tough. Where does this data even come from?

Comment: I'm not really sure on how it was generated this way. It was not in a way that I require for  further processing.

Answer (score 3):

```
In [300]: [np.array([' '.join(ij) for ij in zip(*np.atleast_2d(row))]) for row in data]        
Out[300]: 
[array(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype='<U1'),
 array(['d g', 'e h', 'f i'], dtype='<U3'),
 array(['j m p', 'k n q', 'l o r'], dtype='<U5')]
```

The first array is 1d, thus requiring the `atleast_2d` for consistency.  Most the rest is just iterative application of string `join`.

Comment: very nice use of `np.atleast_2d` :) +1

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
res=list(map(lambda x: list(map(' '.join, zip(*x))) if isinstance(x[0], list) else x, data))
```

Outputs:

```py
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d g', 'e h', 'f i'], ['j m p', 'k n q', 'l o r']]
```

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski Thank you but I'm getting this error `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, Timestamp found`

Comment: Try: ```res=list(map(lambda x: list(map(lambda z: ' '.join([str(el) for el in z]), zip(*x))) if isinstance(x[0], list) else x, data))```

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski I tried but it's not working. I mean the error is gone but it returns input data as output. It's not joining

Comment: Ok, since it's not a ```list```, but ```numpy``` try: ```res=list(map(lambda x: list(map(lambda z: ' '.join([str(el) for el in z]), zip(*x))) if isinstance(x[0], np.ndarray) else x, data))```

Answer (score 1):

Since you say there are also timestamp values, I cast to string for every sub-array.

```
out = [[' '.join(tup) for tup in zip(*arr.astype(str))] if arr.ndim > 1 else arr.tolist() 
               for arr in data]

Out[89]: [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d g', 'e h', 'f i'], ['j m p', 'k n q', 'l o r']]
```